# Как вывести сообщение в консоль из приложения Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, консоль

Приложение может запускаться с параметрами. Есть необходимость вывести хелп с параметрами в этой же консоли, где было запущено приложение, если пользователь ошибся, скажем так. Как при запуске приложения в этой же консоли вывести сообщение?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` не подходит?

Comment: не выводит ничего

Comment: А у вас консольное приложение?

Comment: Нет, не консольное. WinForms

Comment: Тогда где должна появляться справка, если юзер запускает программу через проводник?

Comment: Справка есть и в самой программе. Дело в том, что эту программу он может запускать из командной строки со своими атрибутами. Программа выполнилась и все. Сама форма нужна только для конфигурирования. При наличии ошибок хотелось бы вывести в консоли хелп.

Comment: Это понятно. А что должно произойти, если программа запускается не из командной строки с неправильными параметрами? Соответственно, никакой консоли нет.

Comment: Выведите окно-справку и все проблемы.

Comment: VladD, Если просто из проводника - то форма для конфигурирования. А над вопросом вашим нужно подумать, не могу сказать.

Comment: В случае неверных параметров я все скидываю в лог.

Comment: 4per, как вариант. но удобней для пользователя именно в этой консоли

Comment: Rasul, можешь сбросить ссылку?

Comment: Сделать приложение изначально консольным: в свойствах проекта поменять Output type на Console Application. Тогда консоль будет выводиться всегда. Даже если запустить приложение не через консоль. При неправильных параметрах в неё можно стандартно вывести любую информацию с помощью `Console.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `cmd.exe` не обрабатывает вывод приложений с графическим интерфейсом. При запуске оболочка проверяет [флажок в заголовке исполняемого файла](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx#windows_subsystem), и если приложение оконное, то оно запускается не блокируя консоль. После этого можно запустить другое приложение, выполнять команды, либо вовсе закрыть окно консоли. Соответственно, если после этого в консоли будут выводиться сообщения, то будет неясно от какого процесса они исходят.

Предлагаю рассмотреть альтернативные варианты:

1. Выводить сообщение об ошибке в графическом интерфейсе. Раз все приложение оконное, то и сообщение логично показывать в интерфейсе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. С помощью Win32 присоединять консольный вывод к родительскому процессу  через [`AttachConsole`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole) и насильно писать в него:

   ```
   //импорт функции
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
   static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

   //присоединяемся к родительскому процессу
   AttachConsole(-1)
   //пишем в консоль
   Console.WriteLine("Some message");
   ```

Это будет выглядеть странно, особенно если в консоли будет запущен другой процесс. Так же если понадобится перенаправление потока вывода, то его придется реализовывать самому.

3. Сделать приложение консольным (изменить тип вывода в настройках проекта Visual Studio). В этом случае будет работать вывод в консоль. Недостаток в том, что окно консоли появится даже при запуске в проводнике. Консоль можно скрывать с помощью [`ShowWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx), но полностью избежать его появления не получится.

Comment: Первый вариант и красивый и простой.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант, в Win32 работает (в с# не пробовал). Перед записью в консоль, нужно вызвать `AllocConsole()` из kernel32 и всё.

Comment: @nick_n_a да, тоже вариант.

Comment: @nick_n_a проверил, [`AllocConsole`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole) создаст новую консоль, но в родительскую писать не будет. Можете оформить вариант отдельным ответом, я бы плюсанул.

Comment: Появился вопрос, выходит AttachConsole не сработает если нет "родительской консоли", а  AllocConsole - наоборот? Т.е. самый лучший вариант `if (!AttachConsole(-1)) AllocConsole ()` ?... Ещё момент а в родителе работает программа, и у родителя как, будет каша?)))

Comment: @nick_n_a Насколько я понял `AllocConsole` сработает в любом случае (создаст новую консоль). Насчет поведения лучше у автора вопроса уточнить, из условия не ясно нужна ли своя консоль если «родительской» нет.

Comment: @nick_n_a да, после `AttachConsole` в родителе сообщения появляются ниоткуда, если при этом родитель занят другим процессом, то будет каша.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно создать новую консоль [AllocConsole](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole)

```
//импорт функции
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
//....
// Присоиденить консоль
AllocConsole();
```

и перед выводом её один раз вызвать. Будет создана новая консоль. (Одна консоль на один процесс, т.е. если вызвать из процесса повторно - две не будет).

Если нужно таки писать в родительскую консоль, то можно соиденить AttachConsole и AllocConsole например так

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
//
if (!AttachConsole(-1)) AllocConsole ();
```

но тогда может возникнуть "конфликт" - два приложения будут писать в одну консоль. Но если обе будут выводить "законченые" (всегда заканчивающиеся переводом каретки, например) и "простые" (без атрибутов цветов очистки экрана и т п) предложения - то возможно не будут мешать друг другу.